# How to print http request when using Dispatch and Scala

Tags: scala, http, scala-dispatch

When I am using Dispatch library and Scala, for debugging purpose, how to print out the entire HTTP request with headers, etc. in text  after writing a statement like this ?

```
val svc = url("http://api.hostip.info/country.php")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest version of the lib, `url(...)` returns a `Req`, which is just a thin wrapper around `com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilder`.  You can get the underlying request object with `svc.toRequest`, which you can then call `toString` on or combine the other methods available depending on what information you're really after.  More info:

[Java doc for Request](http://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/Request.html)

[Source for dispatch](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/requests.scala)

Answer (score 8):

Dispatch is based on Netty.io, which fully implements the sl4j logging facade. The debug logging is already being done for you by:

```
com.ning.http.client
```

**Beware**, it logs a **LOT** of crap. I am assuming you are using `ch.qos.logback` for logging purposes:

Go to `src/main/resources`, create a file called `default.logback.xml`, and add the following to it:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```